# Powershell - Should take only set of numbers from file name

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a script that read a file name from path location and then he takes only the numbers and do something with them. Its working fine until I encounter with this situation.

For an example:

For the file name `Patch_1348968.vip` it takes the number `1348968`.
In the case the file name is `Patch_1348968_v1.zip` it takes the number `13489681` that is wrong.

I am using this to fetch the numbers. In general it always start with `patch_#####.vip` with 7-8 digits so I want to take only the digits
before any sign like `_` or `-`.

```
$PatchNumber = $file.Name -replace "[^0-9]" , ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$PatchNumber = $file.Name -replace '.*[-_](\d+).*', '$1'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rSqkXq/1).

**Details**:

- `.*` - any chars other than newline char as many as possible
- `[-_]` - a `-` or `_`
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (`$1`): one or more digits
- `.*` - any chars other than newline char as many as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-match-and--notmatch) instead, so you don't have to think inverted:

```sh
if( $file.Name -match '\d+' ) {
    $PatchNumber = $matches[0]
}
```

`\d+` matches the first consecutive sequence of digits. The automatic variable `$matches` contains the full match at index 0, if the `-match` operator successfully matched the input string against the pattern.

If you want to be more specific, you could use a more complex pattern and extract the desired sub string using a *capture group*:

```sh
if( $file.Name -match '^Patch_(\d+)' ) {
    $PatchNumber = $matches[1]
}
```

Here, the *anchor* `^` makes sure the match starts at the beginning of the input string, then `Patch_` gets matched literally (case-insensitive), followed by a group of consecutive digits which gets captured `()` and can be extracted using `$matches[1]`.

You can get an even more detailed explanation of the RegEx and the ability to experiment with it at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qaZd1L/1).